# How do I permit my Azure Website to access my Azure Cloud Service

Tags: wcf, security, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure Cloud service that I only want to be accessible to my Azure website (multiple environments) and my local office computer.

In my ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg I have some permit and deny rules, with the last one being :

```
  <Rule action="deny" description="denypublic" order="4" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
```

However, how do I find my website's IP so I can add a permit rule for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Websites don't have a fixed outbound IP address, so changing your cloud service `cscfg` won't help (nor will setting ACLs on the port endpoints), since you'll have no IP address to work with. If you want your cloud service accessible only by your website, you'll need to add both your website and your cloud service to a virtual network.